# Calculating $Res_{z=w} {f'(z)\over f(z)} $?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series

I have $$f(z) = \sum_{n=m}^\infty a_n (z-w)^n $$

where $0 < | z-w | < r$ and $a_m \neq 0$ and am asked to calculate

$$Res_{z=w} {f'(z)\over f(z)} $$

I have differentiated $f(z)$ to get $\sum_{n=m}^\infty na_n(z-w)^{n-1}$ and tried dividing, to get $\sum_{n=m}^\infty {n\over (z-w)}$ but this seems wrong. Can anyone help?

Comment: Write $f(z) = (z-w)^m\cdot g(z)$, with a holomorphic $g$ such that $g(w) = a_m \neq 0$.

Comment: How do I do this and where do I go from there?

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=m}^\infty a_n(z-w)^m = (z-w)^m \underbrace{\sum_{n=m}^\infty a_n (z-w)^{n-m}}_{g(z)}.$$

The assumption $a_m \neq 0$ guarantees that $g$ is holomorphic in $w$ with $g(w) = a_m \neq 0$. Then we have $f'(z) = m(z-w)^{m-1}g(z) + (z-w)^m g'(z)$ by the product rule, and hence

$$\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} = \frac{m(z-w)^{m-1}g(z) + (z-w)^m g'(z)}{(z-w)^m g(z)} = \frac{m}{z-w} + \frac{g'(z)}{g(z)}.$$

The last term is holomorphic in $w$.

Comment: Very nice indeed. This trick appears, for example, in the proof of the Argument Principle. +1

Comment: How do I get from this to the residue?

Comment: What is the residue of each of the two summands in $z = w$?